# A basic question on mutually orthogonal coordinate systems

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, jacobian, information-geometry

I am reading the first chapter of [Information Geometry and its applications by Amari](https://www.springer.com/in/book/9784431559771). I am struggling to grasp a basic concept about mutually orthogonal coordinate systems. Since the book is not available for free, I will elaborate on the problem in detail.

In the first chapter, the author introduces the definition of Manifold $M$ and one of the many coordinate systems on the manifold, say, $\theta$.

The length of the curve from $\boldsymbol {\theta}$ to $\boldsymbol{ \theta + d\theta}$ is given by $$
d s^{2}=2 D_{\psi}[\theta : \theta+d \theta]=\sum g_{i j} d \theta^{i} d \theta^{j}
$$

A tangent vector can be expressed as $$
d \boldsymbol{\theta}=\sum d \theta^{i} \boldsymbol{e}_{i}
$$ where $
\left\{\boldsymbol{e}_{i}\right\}
$, $i \in \{1,.. ,n\}$ are the basis of the tangent space of M at point  $\boldsymbol \theta$. Similarly, the author introduces a dual affine coordinate system whose corresponding basis is $\left\{e^{* i}\right\}$. Therefore,we can write

$$
d \boldsymbol \theta^{*}=\sum d \theta_{i}^{*} e^{* i}
$$

Now, one can also write the length of the small line vector as $$
d s^{2}=\langle d \boldsymbol{\theta}, d \boldsymbol{\theta}\rangle= g_{i j} d \theta^{i} d \theta^{j}
$$, which is rewritten as $$
d s^{2}=\left\langle d \theta^{i} e_{i}, d \theta^{j} e_{j}\right\rangle=\left\langle e_{i}, e_{j}\right\rangle d \theta^{i} d \theta^{j}
$$
Hence, it is clear that $$
g_{i j}(\boldsymbol{\theta})=\left\langle\boldsymbol{e}_{i}, \boldsymbol{e}_{j}\right\rangle
$$

Similarly, for the dual affine coordinate system $\boldsymbol \theta^*$, we have $$
g^{* i j}(\boldsymbol \theta^*)=\left\langle e^{* i}, e^{* j}\right\rangle
$$

If $\bf G$ is the Jacobian of the transformation from $\boldsymbol \theta$ to $\boldsymbol \theta^*$, then we can write 
$$
\begin{array}{l}{d \boldsymbol{\theta}^{*}=\mathbf{G} d \boldsymbol{\theta}, \quad d \boldsymbol{\theta}=\mathbf{G}^{-1} d \boldsymbol{\theta}^{*}} \\ {d \theta_{i}^{*}=g_{i j} d \theta^{j}, \quad d \theta^{j}=g^{* j i} d \theta_{i}^{*}}\end{array}
$$

I was able to follow till this point. I am unable to understanding how the author says the following:

> The two bases $\left\{e_{ i}\right\}$ and $\left\{e^{* i}\right\}$ are mutually reciprocal or dual - because $$
> e^{* i}=g^{i j} e_{j}, \quad e_{i}=g_{i j} e^{* j}
> $$ and hence, $$
> \langle e_{i}, e^{* j}\rangle=\delta_{i}^{j}
> $$

What is the meaning of $\delta_{i}^{j}$? Can you please give a proof of how this follows?

Thank you,

Comment: Wikipedia [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis).

Comment: @Somos: Does this mean that "tangent space of a convex function and the tangent space of its Legendre transform always form a dual basis"?

Comment: I don't see any Legendre Transform here, whatever that is.

Comment: $\delta_i^j=\begin{cases}1&i=j\\ 0& O.W\end{cases}$.

Comment: @Somos: I have read and understood how dual basis can be constructed. But, I think there is something amiss in the textbook I was referring to in the question. Because given two basis that satisfy $e^{* i}=g^{i j} e_{j}, \quad e_{i}=g_{i j} e^{* j}$, I do not see how $\left\langle e_{i}, e^{* j}\right\rangle = \delta_j^i$. Can you please explain how this follows

Comment: This is an extension of the definition of your metric, I believe. How is the metric defined? The delta should just be a coincidence of your choice of metric coupled with orthogonality.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: The metric is defined on an affine coordinate system. The author talks about an affine coordinate system and the corresponding dual affine coordinate system in this regard.

Comment: @kasa The dual coordinate system is composed of the same index vectors, the only difference is they do not form a basis unless they also span the space. But since the vectors make up the same index, orthogonality still holds, which implies that the inner product is equal to the Kronecker delta. This is a common result of orthogonal basis vectors in any coordinate system. You're just seeing that it also holds in a dual space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows straight from the transformations that have been developed, namely

$$\left< \hat{e}_i, \hat{e}^{*j}\right> = (\sum_k g_{ik}\hat{e}^{*k}) \cdot \hat{e}^{*j} = \sum_k g_{ik}g^{kj} =  \delta_i^j = \begin{cases}
0 \ i\neq j\\
1 \ i = j
\end{cases}$$

As the author states in the text, that the basis $\{ e_i \}$ or $\{ e^{i*} \}$ may not be individually orthogonal but they are mutually orthogonal.